# Error in exporting image from picturebox " A generic error occurred in GDI+. " C#

Tags: c#

I have an error when exporting image from pictureBox

" A generic error occurred in GDI+ "

************** Exception Text **************

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
at Soccer_Studio.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in ***********************\Form1.cs:line 137
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

This is my code

```
 using (Bitmap tempImage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image))
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"C:\Users\Mena\Desktop", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }
```

What is the problem in the code ?

Comment: `A generic error occurred in GDI+`, that really doesn't say too much. What does the debugger say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need a filename...

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"C:\Users\Mena\Desktop\file.bmp",
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: Emphasis on the `file.bmp` in the path.